# GWT: When to use AsyncProxy<T> instead of AsyncProvider<T,F>?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to wrap my head around GWT's [`AsyncProvider<T,F>`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/core/client/AsyncProvider.html) and [`AsyncProxy<T>`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/AsyncProxy.html) classes. I understand the concept behind the **Async Provider pattern**: it allows you to structure code such that an exclusive fragment (module) is associated with an `AsyncProvider` implementation. Then, anytime you want to work with that module, you code against the API provided by that `AsyncProvider` impl. Easy enough...

But the `AsyncProxy` is throwign me off. According to the JavaDocs:

> The AsyncProxy type is used to provide a reachability barrier between classes intended to be used with runAsync while maintaining a simple, deferred-synchronous API. The first invocation of an instance method on the AsyncProxy will trigger the instantiation of a concrete object via runAsync.

But isn't this what the `AsyncProvider` is already supposed to do?!? If someone could give me a concrete for-instance as to when I would use `AsyncProxy` instead of an `AsyncProvider` I think things would fall together and I'd be able to make sense of the rest of its JavaDocs.

Comment: If I understand the `AsyncProxy` documentation, it's there to wrap an object that can be created in a deferred fashion. Basically, your code "thinks" it runs with a real instance of the proxied class, but instead the methods you call on it will only actually get executed after the async call completes. I don't think they have dramatically different use cases. You'd use the proxy when you want to have transparency and avoid cluttering your code with callbacks; and you use the provider when you want more control over the process - like handling failures.

Comment: Ahhh - thanks @millimoose (+1). Can you think of a specific use case or example when one would use an `AsyncProxy`? It *sounds* like its just a way of creating an object whose instance methods will get executed at some point in time after they are called, but not necessarily immediately. If this is the case, it sounds exactly what like a `Scheduler`/`DeferredCommand` does. A concrete code example might help me fill in the gaps here. Thanks again!

Comment: Honestly I'm not very experienced in GWT, I'm mostly going by the documentation and general knowledge here. (Hence the vague comments instead of a full answer.) I think the advantage of an `AsyncProxy` doing the same, with more transparency. You can think of the proxy as "automagically" generating `DeferredCommand`s for you, that defer the method call that was proxied.

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncProxy` is just another way to use [code splitting](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting), e.g. it is basically syntactic sugar, which can be used instead of `GWT.runAsync`

Let's say you have some class which is able to display some complex popup with analytics.

```
public class InformationResolver {

    public void showAnalytics(String targetId){
        //lots of complicated logic here
    }         

}
```

We know that functionality provided by this class isn't the first thing the user will want to use. So it is perfect candidate for code splitting. And it has only void methods, it is really is easy to achieve it with `AsyncProxy`.

First, we extract interface:

```
  interface InformationResolverIfc{ void showAnalytics(String targetId);}
```

Original class will implement this interface. Than we create a proxy interface:

```
@ConcreteType(InformationResolver.class)
 interface ResolverProxy extends AsyncProxy<InformationResolverIfc>, InformationResolverIfc {}
```

Now, when we are in some point of time we want to invoke `showAnalytics` method, we do following:

```
InfomationResolverIfc resolver=GWT.create(ResolverProxy.class);
resolver.showAnalytics("gwt");
```

So what you have here is that you can freely and easily use functionality provided by `InformationResolver` at any place in your application, but implementation code for this class will be downloaded only when it is actually used for the first time. And you don't have to use `GWT.runAsync` at all. There is only one problem, `AsyncProxy` can be used only for classes with only void methods (because you can't get anything from the class which is not loaded yet).